# Wrapping comma-separated items with divs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I split a string in jQuery by commas, wrap each item in a div, and then convert it back to a string?

I've got a solution which almost works, however it prefaces each string with "undefined".

```
var tags = item.tags.split(',');
var taglist;
$.each(tags, function(t, tag){
    taglist += "<div class='tag'>" + tag + "</div>";
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`taglist` is not defined before using, hence the result

```
var taglist = "";
```

Try with the above declaration

Answer (score 1):

You have instantiated taglist but it is not defined.  Try this:

```
var taglist = "";
```